# Keep div width after expanding it with hover (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to keep a div's width after expanding it doing hover on another element. That's my code:

CSS:

```
div.container{
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
border: 1px solid;
clear: both;

}

.square{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;  
background: black;
float: left;
position: relative;
}

.grow {
width: 0px;
height: 100px;
float: left;
background: black; 
position: relative; 
transition:width 0.5s; 
-webkit-transition:width 0.5s;
background: green;
}

.square:hover + .grow {
width: 200px; 
}
```

And there's my html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="grow"></div>
</div>
```

I want a only CSS solution. I know that it's simple with JS, but I really need this using CSS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would just set it to `position: absolute` so that it doesn't get considered for the layout of the container.

Comment: When you are not hovering over `.square`, the `.grow` div will revert back to the original width.  You need JavaScript/jQuery for this since you are trying to control events and behavior.  CSS is for styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set an **extremely high transition time for the shrinking animation** part, which will give the effect of not shrinking. No js required, just setting it to something like 3600s (maybe try even higher?) which will be an hour will give you a visually static for a long time. I couldn't find the maximum time but it seems to work.

```css
div.container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
    clear: both;
}

.square{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    background: black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    transition:width 5s; 
    -webkit-transition:width 5s;
}

.grow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: black; 
    position: relative; 
    transition:width 3600s; 
    -webkit-transition:width 3600s;
    background: green;
}

.square:hover + .grow{
    width: 200px; 
    transition:width 0.5s; 
    -webkit-transition:width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="grow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @easwee encountered the same problem some time ago, ended up using jquery but this would've done the trick

Answer (score 2):

Using animation (rather than a transition) is an option:

```css
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    background: black;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.grow {
    width: 0;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: black; 
    position: relative; 
    transition: width 0.5s; 
    background: green;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-name: extend;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.square:hover + .grow {
    animation-play-state: running;    
}

@keyframes extend {
    0% { width: 0; }
    100% { width: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="grow"></div>
</div>
```

[Lea Verou](http://lea.verou.me/2014/01/smooth-state-animations-with-animation-play-state/)'s article is a good read: basically we're toggling the `animation-play-state` between `paused` and `running`, and using `animation-fill-mode` to ensure the expanded div keeps the styling we want once the animation is complete. There's a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/Lcbateqm/).

The downside here is if you hover the `.square` but take the cursor off before the animation finishes, then the `.grow.` div is 'stuck' halfway (this may or may not be a problem, and it'll probably be an issue with any CSS-only solution).